# What tool to use to cut audio at specific times via cli interactively?

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, mp3

I have the following situation: I want to cut a large mp3 file into a bunch of smaller ones. But since this is a long mp3 file (really long), I want to listen to it and press something like the space bar when I want to set a "cut point", and when I then press a key, it should prompt me for a filename to save this segment as.
I also need the possibility to skip forwards like 1 second, 10 seconds or a minute.

So I imagine it as this:

> interactive_cut audio.mp3

> Starting audio playback...

Pressing Space now.

> The audio is paused. The chosen segment was from 00:00:00 to 00:00:10. Press "s" to save it as.

Pressing "s" now.

> What filename do you want to save this snippet as? STDIN Filename prompt

... and then the file is saved and the playback continues until I press Space again.

This would be of really great help. I have not found anything that can do this seemingly simple task.

Comment: Your title asks for a command line interface but your description sounds like you want a GUI application like Audacity

Comment: I want it as convienent as possible without extra hassles, so it should run in the command line as a command line program, like htop.

Answer (score 0):

This really stupid and ugly bash script does exactly what I want:

```
#!/bin/bash

ScreenName=VlcScreen
LogFile=TESTLOG
FileName=$1

if [[ ! -e ${FileName} ]]; then
    echo "The file ${FileName} does not exist"
    exit
fi

if [[ -e ${LogFile} ]]; then
    rm ${LogFile}
fi

function start_rvlc_screen {
    screen -d -m -S ${ScreenName} sh -c "rvlc $1 > ${LogFile}"
}

function pause_vlc {
    screen -S ${ScreenName} -p 0 -X stuff "pause^M"
}

function get_time {
    screen -S ${ScreenName} -p 0 -X stuff "get_time^M"
    #currentTimestamp=$(cat ${LogFile} | tail -n2 | head -n1 | sed -e 's/\r//' | sed -e 's/^(> )*//')
    currentTimestamp=$(cat ${LogFile} | tail -n2 | head -n1 | sed -e 's/\r//' | sed -e 's/^\(> \)*//')
    currentTimestamp=$(($currentTimestamp + 1))
    echo "${currentTimestamp}"
}

function seek {
    seek_value=$1
    if [ "${seek_value}" -lt "0" ]; then
        seek_value=0
    fi
    echo "Seeking ${seek_value}"
    screen -S ${ScreenName} -p 0 -X stuff "seek ${seek_value}^M"
}

function quit {
    screen -S ${ScreenName} -p 0 -X stuff "quit^M"
}

function kill_screens {
    screen -XS $(screen -ls | grep ${ScreenName} | sed -e 's/^\s*//' | sed -e 's/\..*//') quit
}

function exit_program {
    kill_screens
    stty sane
    exit
}

function cut_part_from_file {
    FROM=$1
    TO=$2

    FROM=$(($FROM - 1))
    TO=$(($TO - 1))

    LENGTH=$(($TO - $FROM))

    mkdir -p parts

    tmp="$RANDOM.mp3"
    while [[ -e $tmp ]]; do
        tmp="$RANDOM.mp3"
    done

    ffmpeg -ss $FROM -i $FileName -t $LENGTH -c copy $tmp

    
    exitstatus=1
    while [[ "$exitstatus" -ne "0" ]]; do
        play $tmp > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
        TEXT=$(whiptail --inputbox "Was wurde gesagt?" 8 39 "" --title "Example Dialog" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
        exitstatus=$?
    done


    mv $tmp "parts/${TEXT}.mp3"
}

trap exit_program SIGINT
trap exit_program 0

start_rvlc_screen $1

CUT_START=
CUT_END=

while true; do
    read -n1 -p "[q]uit, [p]ause, go [b]ack 10 sec, [B]ack 60s, [f]orward 10s, [F]orward 60s, [c]ut start/end, [k]ancel recording: " input
    echo ""

    if [ "$input" = "p" ]; then 
        pause_vlc
        get_time
    elif [ "$input" = "q" ]; then 
        exit_program

    elif [ "$input" = "f" ]; then 
        CURRENT_TIME=$(get_time)
        SEEK_TIME=$(($CURRENT_TIME + 10))
        seek $SEEK_TIME
    elif [ "$input" = "F" ]; then 
        CURRENT_TIME=$(get_time)
        SEEK_TIME=$(($CURRENT_TIME + 60))
        seek $SEEK_TIME

    elif [ "$input" = "b" ]; then 
        CURRENT_TIME=$(get_time)
        SEEK_TIME=$(($CURRENT_TIME - 10))
        seek $SEEK_TIME
    elif [ "$input" = "B" ]; then 
        CURRENT_TIME=$(get_time)
        SEEK_TIME=$(($CURRENT_TIME - 60))
        seek $SEEK_TIME

    elif [ "$input" = "k" ]; then 
        CUT_START=
        CUT_END=
    elif [ "$input" = "c" ]; then 
        if [[ ! -z ${CUT_START} ]]; then
            pause_vlc
            CUT_END=$(get_time)
            echo "CUT FROM $CUT_START TO $CUT_END"
            cut_part_from_file $CUT_START $CUT_END
            CUT_START=
            CUT_END=
            pause_vlc
        else
            CUT_START=$(get_time)
        fi
    fi
done

exit_program
```